# Creating tabs at the bottom of a LayoutDocument in AvalonDock 2.0?

Tags: wpf, xaml, avalondock

How can I create tabs (in XAML) at the bottom of a LayoutDocument in AvalonDock 2.0, like the Code and Design tabs in Visual Studio? (without using a TabControl, of course)

I'd like to end up with tabs at the top, one per document, but then within each document, be able to have multiple "views," with one tab each, at the bottom of the window.

So, you might have "page.htm" as one document, appearing on a tab at the top. Then "source" and "design" as two tabs at the bottom of the open/activated document.

Answer (score 1):

You sould override the default style of the LayoutDocumentPaneControl and for this I'd suggest to take look at one of the provided theme.
Sample code (not tested):

```
<!--MyCustomDocumentPaneControlStyle-->
<Style x:Key="MyCustomDocumentPaneControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentPaneControl}">
    <Setter Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentPaneControl}">
                <Grid ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!--Following border is required to catch mouse events-->
                    <Border Background="Transparent" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                    <Grid Panel.ZIndex="1" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <avalonDockControls:DocumentPaneTabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"/>
                        <avalonDockControls:DropDownButton
                            x:Name="MenuDropDownButton"
                            Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}}"
                            Focusable="False"
                            Grid.Column="1">
                            <avalonDockControls:DropDownButton.DropDownContextMenu>
                                <avalonDockControls:ContextMenuEx
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Model.ChildrenSorted, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                    <avalonDockControls:ContextMenuEx.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:MenuItemEx}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
                                            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{Binding Path=Root.Manager.DocumentPaneMenuItemHeaderTemplate}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplateSelector" Value="{Binding Path=Root.Manager.DocumentPaneMenuItemHeaderTemplateSelector}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="IconTemplate" Value="{Binding Path=Root.Manager.IconContentTemplate}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="IconTemplateSelector" Value="{Binding Path=Root.Manager.IconContentTemplateSelector}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource ActivateCommandLayoutItemFromLayoutModelConverter}}"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </avalonDockControls:ContextMenuEx.ItemContainerStyle>
                                </avalonDockControls:ContextMenuEx>
                            </avalonDockControls:DropDownButton.DropDownContextMenu>
                            <Image Source="/AvalonDock;component/Images/PinDocMenu.png"/>
                        </avalonDockControls:DropDownButton>                            
                    </Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="ContentPanel" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" 
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" 
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" 
                                          ContentSource="SelectedContent" 
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Model.ChildrenCount}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="MenuDropDownButton" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentTabItem Model="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentControl Model="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you have the new style just plug it using the DocumentPaneControlStyle property of the DockingManager:

```
<ad:DockingManager DocumentPaneControlStyle="{StaticResource MyCustomDocumentPaneControlStyle}">
...
</ad:DockingManager>
```

Ado

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I think my question was incomplete (I've updated it). I'm looking for a way to add tabs to the "inside" of a document--like views. If you can do that by applying a style to the DockingManager, how do you define those views within a document?